# for loop and ownership of a container

Tags: rust

I am going through a Rust book at the moment. In it, it states that if I want to be able to reuse the container used in a `for` loop, after the loop, I will need to prefix it with `&` (borrow it?). However, I have tried those four scenarios and they all give me the same result.

Segment 2 reuses the container from Segment 1.
Segment 3 and Segment 4 use & with the same outcome.

What am I missing?

```
fn main() {

    let _needle = 32;
    let haystack = [1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862];

// Segment 1

    for item in haystack {
        let result = match item {
            42 | 132 => "hit",
            _ => "miss"
        };

        if result == "hit" {
            println!("{}: {}", item, result);
        }
    }

// Segment 2

    for item in haystack {
        let result = match item {
            42 | 132 => "hit",
            _ => "miss"
        };

        if result == "hit" {
            println!("{}: {}", item, result);
        }
    }

// Segment 3

    for item in &haystack {
        let result = match *item {
            42 | 132 => "hit",
            _ => "miss"
        };

        if result == "hit" {
            println!("{}: {}", *item, result);
        }
    }    

// Segment 4

    for item in &haystack {
        let result = match item {
            42 | 132 => "hit",
            _ => "miss"
        };

        if result == "hit" {
            println!("{}: {}", item, result);
        }
    }

    println!("{}", haystack[0]);

}
```

Results:

```
42: hit
132: hit
42: hit
132: hit
42: hit
132: hit
42: hit
132: hit
1
```

Comment: I *think* that what may be misleading you is that what you take is not the container, but what it contains, in a `for` loop. However, in your case, what's inside your container is `Copy`, in the sense that Rust can implicitly create copies of it instead of taking ownership, if needed, so you won't see the difference. Trying testing on vectors of something else than numbers.

Comment: @BlackBeans It's not the type of element that matters but the type of container. `[T; _]` is `Copy` when `T: Copy`.

Answer (score 2):

The "trick" is that `haystack` is a `[i32; N]`, and, according to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html),

> Arrays of any size implement the following traits if the element type allows it:
>
> - Copy
> - Clone
> - Debug
> - IntoIterator (implemented for [T; N], &[T; N] and &mut [T; N])
> - PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord
> - Hash
> - AsRef, AsMut
> - Borrow, BorrowMut

So it's actually impossible to move out of `haystack` because it's `Copy`. If you replace it with a `Vec<i32>` you'll get the behavior you expect.